# Subclassing UIButton and overriding touch events - not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uiviewanimation

I need a scale spring animation for all my buttons in a project.
So i subclassed UIButton and override touch event functions.

```
import UIKit

class UIAnimatedButton: UIButton {

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.8, 0.8)

    })
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

}

override func touchesCancelled(touches: Set<NSObject>!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {


    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
        initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, withEvent: event)
    }

}


override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5,
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
        initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }) { (Bool) -> Void in
            super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
    }
  }
}
```

this works great in a fast tap but when i touch the button for a long time (1-2 seconds) i don't get a touch up inside action event.
when i switch it back to a regular UIButton everything works fine.

Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: where not otherwise specified by the documentation the first thing to do in an overridden method is to call the super. It's a little bit strange call it inside an animation block.

Comment: if i call super before the animation ended, the animation will not animate. Do you have any way to make this animation?

Comment: Instead overriding the UIGestureRecognizer methods try to use the methods `beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:`, `continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` and 
`endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:` of the UIControl class of which the UIButton is a subclass.

Comment: this doesn't work... the animation is not being animated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of calling super in the completion block of `touchesCancelled` and `touchesEnded` methods I called `self.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)` in there.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly why yet, but you need to call `super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)` outside the animation

So (Swift 5)

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
        delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2,
        initialSpringVelocity: 6.0,
        options: UIView.AnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction,
        animations: { () -> Void in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }) { (Bool) -> Void in
    }
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach that works as of Swift 5, so UIButton subclass can intercept its button push, and forward the registered target/action listeners external to the button class:

1. In the UIView superview of the subclassed button:

   ```
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPushed), 
       for: .primaryActionTriggered)
   ```
2. In button subclass, detect button press by adding this to `init()` method:

   ```
    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, 
           action: #selector(buttonPressed))
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired    = 1;
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
   ```
3. Trap button press inside the subclass with a handler:

   ```
    @objc func buttonPressed() {
       // .
       // . (do whatever subclass needs to)
       // .
       self.sendActions(for: .primaryActionTriggered)
    }
   ```

Without sendActions, the gestureRecognizer that was added in init will prevent the event from being propagated to the consumers in the ResponderChain.